# SQLAlchemy: One select is executing multiple selects against Postgres DB

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Can anyone with deeper SQLAlchemy knowledge explain why it appears to be sending multiple queries to the DB instead of just the one as explained below?

The query looks like the following:

```
session.query(Orders).filter(
    Orders.user_id == user_id,
    Orders.created_on <= now,
    Orders.created_on > 30_days_ago
).order_by(
    Orders.status, 
    Orders.created_on.desc()
).all()
```

(Orders.status is simply an integer like 1 => "shipped" 2 => "complete" 3 => "returned")

I expected a single query emitted to the DB with reasonably the same logic as (in Postgres):

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE
    user_id = :user_id and
    created_on < now() and
    created_on >= now() - interval '30 days'
ORDER BY status, created_on DESC;
```

Assume the above query returned 10 rows with ids 1-11.
What was actually seen emitted to the DB from the Postgres logs was an individual query for each row that would have been retrieved.

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE id = 1;

SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE id = 2;

SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE id = 3;

...
```

Ended up having to use `session.execute()` instead of `session.query()`. Luckily in this case the app is not dependent on the session being up to date.

Edit - adding more info about Orders model

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Orders(Base)
    __tablename__ = "Orders"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, index=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, index=True, index=True)
    category = Column(String, nullable=False)
    status = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    created_on = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, user_id, name, category, status, created_on):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.name = name
        self.category = category
        self.status = priority
        self.created_on = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

The table has an index on the user_id column and the name column.

Comment: Haven't seen that behaviour with similar queries, not in SQLAlchemy logging anyway. Can you show how your `Orders` is defined?

Comment: @bgse added the definition of the Orders model, it is using declarative_base

Comment: Please include a [mcve] – a minimal sample that people can pretty much copy & paste in order to verify the observed behaviour. For example what does `user_id` contain?

Comment: Have you perhaps btw after querying issued a rollback, commit, or expunged the results before using them? That would explain the observed behaviour: once you'd start using the order objects SQLAlchemy would have to refresh them, one by one. So: include an actual mcve.

Comment: Moreover, if a table has any FK, sqlalchemy will make additional SELECT for each fk value to linked table. Whata madness